# Conditionally support credentials based on origin. A good Idea?

Tags: cookies, cors, cross-domain, flask-cors

So this question is not really related to flask but a question in general about CORS.
I happen to be using flask api though. I want to conditionally support_credentials to my endpoint if the origin of the request is from some specific domains...otherwise reject credentials.

I was surprised that this did not seem to be supported in flask under the hood.
I have been trying to find similar use cases online but its hard to find this.
So I am now wondering if what I want to do is a good idea or not.
Perhaps for such a scenario there are other recommended ways?

Basically my endpoint is shared among multiple origins and I want to give some origins more privileges, as regards sending cookies to the endpoint, than others.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to allow some origins _with_ credentials and allow others _without_ credentials? CORS libraries typically don't let you configure CORS at such a granular level; either all allowed origins have credentialed access, or none of them do. I'd be curious to hear more about your use case... If I wanted to do this, I would probably provide two distinct endpoints with two distinct CORS configurations.

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do exactly. Allow some origins and reject others.
I fail to see how allowing all or none is better that allowing some.
Making different endpoints is not an option right now.

Comment: It sounds to me like a solution in search of a problem :) Can you clarify why you would want to allow credentialed access for some of the allowed origins and not the others?

Comment: Well...my endpoints are used by third parties via a js library. I want to give some privileges and others not

Comment: Ok, but why? How are some clients worthy of credentialed access and others not?

Comment: My assumption is that it is more secure to allow credentials from only a specified domain. Since I do not expect some domains to send credentials, it seems I may not want to open wide for all clients.
Allowing credentials from all origins seems like a bad idea...

Comment: Allowing credentials from all origins is indeed a bad idea. But what's wrong with allowing credentials from a restricted set of origins?

Comment: How do i do that without creating another set of endpoints?
Like i said earlier, the endpoints are shared by all origins